# jqPlot Not Displaying Line Chart In Program But Okay In Stand Alone code

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am trying to display a simple jqPlot two-line chart using jQuery that generates the chart and shows the display area when a specific button is clicked. I can run the code in a separate program on the same server from the same directory just fine, but when I insert it into my code it refuses to render.

I have checked that the js files are all there, in order, and the names are correct. In View Source, I can click on each and view them just fine, so they are being found. In the jQuery, I can display text and show/hide just fine, so my IF logic to display that section is working as is the button-click functionality.  I have been all through Stack Overflow's responses similar to this problem but nothing seems to fit. I have examined jqPlot's documentation ad nauseum to no avail.  I believe it's my near-novice abilities in jQuery that are holding me back.

I need to be sensitive to some content, but here's the top of the program:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class=" ">
<head>  
    <title>company product name</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="blah blah blah" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="some, keywords"/>
    <meta name="author" content="some guy" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" /> 

    <!-- original items for jQuery work -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jobdisplay/myother.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jobdisplay/jquery.table2excel.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css" type="text/css" />

    <!-- jqPlot for line charts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqPlot/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqPlot/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqPlot/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.js"></script>
    <link   type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="js/jqPlot/jquery.jqplot.css" />

    <!-- Bootstrap and other items - original items -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icon.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" type="text/css" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/landing.css" type="text/css" />

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ie/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ie/excanvas.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload=loadRolesTitleSelection();
    </script>
</head>
```

Here's the portion where the charts are to appear -- the chart1 div is for this test only, trying to get something to show:

```
    <section id="trendData" class="panel panel-default" style="display: none; width: 60%; min-width:600px; margin-left: 30px;">
        <header class="panel-heading bg-light">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
                <li class="active"><a href="#rates" data-toggle="tab">Rates</a></li>
                <li><a href="#duration" data-toggle="tab">Open Duration</a></li>
                <li><a href="#jobs" data-toggle="tab">Number of Jobs</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="rates" name="rates" style="height:400px;width:300px;">
                    <p>If only my dog could see me now.</p>
<!-- Plot -->
<div id="chart1"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="duration" style="height:400px;width:300px;">
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="jobs" style="height:400px;width:300px;"> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="trendsResults" class="trendsResults"></div>
    </section>
```

Just below this, oddly enough, I found this, which is from an earlier programmers efforts. BTW, everything works fine until I start loading in this jqPlot code:

```
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- App -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/charts/easypiechart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.plugin.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and when the button is clicked on, this is the simplified, testing version of what it's running:

```
$('#btnTrend').click( function() {
    $('#trendData').show();
    $.jqplot('chart1',  [[[1, 2],[3,5.12],[5,13.1],[7,33.6],[9,85.9],[11,219.9]],
                [[1, 12],[3,15.12],[5,113.1],[7,133.6],[9,185.9],[11,319.9]]]);
});
```

but nothing appears.

Again, a simple version works just fine; to whit:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqPlot/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jqPlot/jquery.jqplot.css" />
<div id="chart1"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.jqplot('chart1',  [[[1, 2],[3,5.12],[5,13.1],[7,33.6],[9,85.9],[11,219.9]],
                [[1, 12],[3,15.12],[5,113.1],[7,133.6],[9,185.9],[11,319.9]]]);
    });
</script>
```

I want to be able to click on btnTrend and have it generate the chart in the location specified. Eventually, I'll embellish the chart and pull the code from an API and deal with it in jSON, but for now I need to know the chart will generate before I move on.

Answer (score 0):

Question Answered, mostly.

Disabled the extra line

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and also the unneeded line

```
<script src="js/charts/easypiechart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js"></script>
```

and the chart displays now.   When I have time, I'll go back and figure out which was the offending party, but I have to get this project done so I'm happy to move on.

Answer (score 0):

I got a chance to test with isolation and it was definitely the duplicate jquery.min.js file load that was causing the conflict.   Once I removed the line below (commented it out), jqPlot worked perfectly.

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```